# Android: BaseGameActivity, launch failed

Tags: android, google-play-services

So I read this forum for a long time and always I can find answer for my problems. But this is very strange and I don't know what i should do.

So I make app where i want to use Google Achievment. I have a account on Google, I make the achievement there. I add to my app `GameBaseUtils` as a library and to `GameBaseUtils` google-play-services-lib, too.
So I wanna add achievment to my code. I go with android development site instruction. But when I change

```
public class Home
  extends Activity
```

to

```
public class Home
  extends BaseGameActivity
```

I cannot launch a app. (Aha - i change in BaseGameActivities that this extends Activity not a fragment because i dont use it)

This is my log:

```
10-17 01:32:49.800: W/dalvikvm(19501): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x430d4140)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501): Process: com.oxygenum.wroclawtesty44, PID: 19501
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501): java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$h.b(Unknown Source)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$h.d(Unknown Source)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$b.fv(Unknown Source)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.hb$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
10-17 01:32:49.800: E/AndroidRuntime(19501):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 01:32:53.030: I/Process(19501): Sending signal. PID: 19501 SIG: 9
```

Maybe i do something wrong - but how I can use achievment if I cannot use `BaseGameActvities` so user dont log to Google.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I achieve this is to implement GameHelper in your main activity.  There is no requirement to use fragments if you do not want to.

You could even setup a GameHelper in your fragment activity and call it from your main Activity.

In order to get a pointer to your Google Connection, use GoogleApiClient(). If mHelper was your gameHelper object and it is defined statically in your Fragment activity, then you can call this by using mHelper.GoogleApiClient().

This can be used to add achievements and scores in your leaderboards.